# Selecting Distinct value from one-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: categories, stories and terms. Terms table store categories and stories relationship. Each story can have one or more categories assigned. I want to select only one category for a story. I used `DISTINCT` clause on story_id but it didn't work. Please see following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.story_id, C.cat_id 
  FROM stories S JOIN terms C USING(story_id) 
 LIMIT 3;
```

and result

```
+----------+--------+
| story_id | cat_id |
+----------+--------+
|      115 |     17 |
|      115 |     20 |
|      115 |     21 |
+----------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any clue why is it not picking up unique story_id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...Any clue why is it not picking up unique story_id?

It doesn't return unique story_id because `DISTINCT` applies **to all columns** in `SELECT` clause and not an individual column.

---

Since you *...want to select **only one** category for a story...* you can use an aggregate function `MIN()` or `MAX()` with `GROUP BY` to do that

```
SELECT s.story_id, MIN(c.cat_id) cat_id
  FROM stories s JOIN terms c 
    ON s.story_id = c.story_id
 GROUP BY s.story_id
```

Now since you're returning only `story_id` and `cat_id` you don't even need to join `stories` and `terms`

```
SELECT story_id, MIN(cat_id) cat_id
  FROM terms
 GROUP BY story_id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18467a/3)** demo

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT S.story_id, C.cat_id` will consider both story_id and cat_id as one entity and remove duplicates. if you need to get distinct `story_id` then you can try below

```
SELECT S.story_id, C.cat_id FROM stories AS S
INNER JOIN terms AS C ON(S.cat_id = C.cat_id)
GROUP BY S.story_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.story_id, C.cat_id FROM stories AS S
INNER JOIN terms AS C ON(S.cat_id = C.cat_id)
GROUP BY S.story_id
```

Comment: Never mix `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`